# $.getJSON adds ' http://localhost:3000' to api URL

Tags: jquery, weather-api

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2m4G.png)

I am building Weather-App, and when I call API, `$.getJSON`  adds my localhost addres.

> GET
>   http://localhost:3000/api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=50.064650099999994&lon=19.9449799&APPID=f7dcb8e5d6a1f2126a2080a1e0d17b5a
>   404 (Not Found)

```
$("#getLocation").on("click", function() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            $("#location").html("latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + "<br>longitude: " + position.coords.longitude);
            lat = position.coords.latitude;
            lon = position.coords.longitude;

            api = "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + lon + "&APPID=f7dcb8e5d6a1f2126a2080a1e0d17b5a";

            console.log(api);

            $.getJSON(api, function(json) {
                $("#api").html(json);
            });
        });
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the URL doesn't contain `//servername`, it's interpreted as a relative URL from the current page's path. Use:

```
        api = "//api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + lat + "&lon=" + lon + "&APPID=f7dcb8e5d6a1f2126a2080a1e0d17b5a";
```

Comment: thanks, unfortunately documentation is not clear enough

Comment: Any decent tutorial on URLs should explain how they're constructed.